# Is there a better practice for my logo placement and how to center my LI after adding logo?

Tags: html, sass, navbar

So I'm trying to learn HTML/SCSS and I have the problem that I had to specify the exact position of my logo which doesn't make it responsible for mobile. Is there a better practice for this?

[image: This is the specified position for the logo]

You can find the SCSS on this JSFiddle.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6b0hnt2f/3/)

```
 .logo {
        margin-top: -0.7%;
        margin-bottom: -0.5%;
        margin-left: -3.25%;
        height: 45.6px; 
    }
```

Besides that, when I add my photo, the navbar isn't centered any longer and is placed a bit to the right from the center. How can I prevent this from happening?

[image: This is the logo.pgn (using it for JSFiddle)]

Comment: I can't spot where you "specify the exact position of the logo" in that fiddle. Please copy the code you are talking about, [edit] your question and paste it directly to the question. Your image has a large tranparent area around it. This typically complicates positioning.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post and added the code from line 40 to 45. This is where I specify the position. Is cropping the best way to remove the transparent area? ** EDIT** I did crop the sides off the logo, that might fix that problem.

Comment: Ah, I see. Although margins affect the position it just defines extra space around the element. The position itself is determined by the sticky navbar in the normal page flow and the flex container. I would edit the image with an image editor to remove that transparent area. For a logo like yours I would prefer a scalable SVGs over PNG.

Comment: Thanks! Removing the extra space around the logo made it possible to place it in the navbar without specifying position! What would you recommend me to read about according to the navbar so I can center the LI again

Comment: There are multiple ways to keep that menu centered, all with their specific advantages and drawbacks. For instance, you could use the whole width for the menu (so it gets centered) and position the logo above the menu. You could add an empty element with the same size as the logo to the other side of the menu, or you could define a padding or margin on the right side of the menu that matches the size of that logo. I would probably explore the last option to avoid adding extra elements. I'd bet you find a lot of fiddles and examples for stuff like this on the net